# How to write passing test for method containing Devise update_with_password method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I am new to Devise as I have taken on an existing app.
It uses Devise for authentication (without confirmable).
I am trying to write a test for the update method in the users_controller, which uses the update_with_password method.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Either I am not passing in the right parameters to the request (although I checked it with development and modeled test after that (except the form's authenticity_token)), or something else is going wrong.

I am using Test::Unit and fixtures:

In users_controller:

```
def update
    @user = current_account.users.find(params[:id])
    raise @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password]).inspect
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      flash[:notice] = flash_saved
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = flash_not_saved
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

In users_controller_test:

```
test "should update user with password" do
    @user = users(:participant)
    sign_in(@user)
    assert_equal(true, @user.valid_password?('<password>'))
    put :update, {id: @user.id, method: :put, :user => {email: @user.email, password: nil, password_confirmation: nil, current_password: "<password>", firstname: "louis"}, subaccount: "test"}
  end
```

In the fixtures:

```
participant:
  email: participant@test.com
  id: 3
  confirmed_at: 2013-01-01 00:10:00
  account_id: 1
  firstname: participant
  last_sign_in_at: <%= Time.now - 30 %>
  encrypted_password: <encrypted_password>
  password_salt: <password_salt>
```

The assertion in the test returns false, although I copied the encrypted_password and password_salt from a user in development.

The request parameters in development:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hy3IJ8C7qQs+iyxZ/VCnrVWEh9vecZCGrAuxwEWxWEE=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"my@email.com",
 "firstname"=>"",
 "lastname"=>"",
 "gender"=>"",
 "phone1"=>"",
 "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Opslaan",
 "subaccount"=>"experience",
 "id"=>"3087"}
```

The request paramers in test:

```
{"subdomain"=>nil, "method"=>"put", "user"=>{"email"=>"participant@test.com", "firstname"=>"louis"}, "id"=>"3", "subaccount"=>"test", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update"}
```

Somehow it doesn't show the :current_password, although I am sending it in the request.

How can I get this test to pass? Your help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

On first pass it looks ok except for one line.

```
raise @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password]).inspect
```

try removing this line, and seeing if it passes.